# Firebase Database - security consideration in an inverse index

Tags: json, indexing, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

In the Firebase guides, one of the recommendations is to maintain an inverse index to keep track of user actions. Here's a snippet of what I'm referring to:

```
// An index to track Ada's memberships
{
  "users": {
    "alovelace": {
      "name": "Ada Lovelace",
      // Index Ada's groups in her profile
      "groups": {
         // the value here doesn't matter, just that the key exists
         "techpioneers": true,
         "womentechmakers": true
      }
    },
    ...
  },
  "groups": {
    "techpioneers": {
     "name": "Historical Tech Pioneers",
     "members": {
        "alovelace": true,
        "ghopper": true,
        "eclarke": true
      }
    },
    ...
  }
}
```

Each user keeps track of his/her groups in an inverse index - meaning in this case, that the keys hold the real value, and the value doesn't matter.

---

### Update

I wasn't sure how to update the index technically but I got it after a little research: the `setValue` can take all manor of variables, not just key-value pairs. That means that updating an index is pretty simple: just get a reference to `groups/$group_id/members/$member_id` and set its value to `true`.

Now my question is different:

Lets say all groups are private. Meaning users can join a group by invitation only - a current group member must add another user to the member list. So if I'm **ghopper** and I want to add **alovelace** as a member, I need to update her index which is part of her user object - which means I have to know her user ID somehow and have write access to her `groups` field - and that seems like a security risk.

Any thoughts on how to manage this while keeping access as restricted as possible? Perhaps another DB object that maps a user known identifier, like an email to a group list?

Comment: try firebase's [multi-path-updates](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i1n9Kw3AORw)

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1 - Client-side**

One solution would be to have a separate user invitation object so that **ghopper** can add **alovelace** to the private group and have that show up **alovelace's** invitations instead of automatically adding her to the group. **alovelace** would then need to approve the addition and update her group membership. This way, only the user retains access to their user record. This is quite similar to adding friends on facebook, or requesting connections on linkedin.

For illustration, the schema could look something like this

```
// An index to track Ada's memberships
{
  "users": {
    "alovelace": {
      "name": "Ada Lovelace",
      // Index Ada's groups in her profile
      "groups": {
         // the value here doesn't matter, just that the key exists
         // Only Ada can write here
         "techpioneers": true,
         "womentechmakers": true
      }
    },
    ...
  },
  "invitations": {
    "alovelace": {
      "name": "Ada Lovelace",
      "groups": {
         // the value here doesn't matter, just that the key exists
         // Anyone can write here
         "ghoppersfanclub": true, // Ada might accept this and move it to groups
         "explicitcontentgroup": true, // Ada might reject this and delete this entry
      }
    },
    ...
  },
  "groups": {
    "techpioneers": {
     "name": "Historical Tech Pioneers",
     "members": {
        "alovelace": true,
        "ghopper": true,
        "eclarke": true
      }
    },
    ...
  }
}
```

**Solution 2 - Server-side**

Although Firebase is meant to enable building apps without server code, there are instances where you should get the server in the mix. In my opinon, security and the execution of trusted actions like one user making changes to another user's record (if we're not using a separate object like 'invitations' above) should be handled by your trusted server using the admin API. When **ghopper** adds **alovelace** as a member, one possible event sequence would be:

- Check that **ghopper** belongs to the group and can add another user (client-side)
- Send a request to your server with payload that includes group name/id, user sending the request and email of the user being added
- Server then looks up alovelace's user id using the provided email and update the user record.

  ```
  admin.auth().getUserByEmail(alovelace_email)
    .then(function(userRecord) {
      // Add group to alovelace's groups.
      // Trigger a client-side notification using child_changed
      // Allow alovelace to approve or decline addition to group
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log("Error fetching user data:", error);
    });
  ```

The above example uses email as a public/shareable unique identifier, but there's also a similar getUserByPhoneNumber(phoneNumber) method.

Comment: I appreciate your response, but you're basically answering "how to handle security concerns inside FB" with "use something else" which kind of defeats the purpose of the question.

Comment: Not sure i understand your comment. You asked "Any thoughts on how to manage this while keeping access as restricted as possible?" and i answered....manage it in FB, but on your server...admin API afterall is part of firebase. I didn't suggest some other random unrelated application or API as a solution.

Comment: No of course you didn't. But I meant for the scope to be restricted to Firebase, For the sake of evaluating FB. Perhaps my question wasn't clear enough.

Comment: I think i understand your intent better now and I edited my answer accordingly.